# Difference in lme and lme4 in R? Difference from STATA too?

Tags: r, model, lme4, mixed

I'm doing mixed effects modeling (using data at two timepoints), and am wondering why there are difference within R packages and also between programs. Here is a reproducible example:

```
  USArrests$ID <- as.factor(matrix(1:50))
  USArrests <- USArrests[,-c(2,3,4)]
  USArrests$Murder2 <- USArrests$Murder + 5
  library(reshape)
  USArrests <- melt(USArrests, id.vars=c("ID"))[,-2]
  USArrests$time <- c(matrix(rep(0,50)), matrix(50:99))
  m1 <- lme(value ~ time, data=USArrests, random = ~1|ID)
  print(summary(m1))
  m2 <- lmer(value ~ time +(1|ID), data = USArrests, REML=F)
  print(summary(m2))
```

I then import this into Stata and use the code:

```
mixed value time || id:time
```

Even within R, the models are slightly different, although compared to STATA, there is much difference. Why does this difference exist? Is it in the algorithms used to estimate maximum likelihood?

Thanks!

Comment: What is the output of the stata function? What are the coefficients for easier comparison? (I dont have stata installed but getting an idea of the difference would be nice). The answer is likely in the [dokumentation](https://www.stata.com/manuals13/memixed.pdf).

Comment: I don't know about Stata, but the difference between `lme` and `lmer` is caused by the estimation method. The lme model is estimated using ML and the lmer model is estimated using REML. Changing `REML = T` gives the exact same output.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the answer to this question, when I asked a statistician, was due to the estimation method as described in the comment by [Niek](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6418297/niek).

> I don't know about Stata, but the difference between lme and lmer is caused by the estimation method. The lme model is estimated using ML and the lmer model is estimated using REML. Changing REML = T gives the exact same output.